# sz and rz fail to transform files in tmux?

Tags: linux, ssh, tmux

I use `xshell` to SSH to a Linux remote server—running Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4 (Nahant Update 3)—without root. There aren’t any problems to use `sz`, `rz` to transform my files until I start `tmux`. When I type `rz`, the info will shows as follows:

```
rz waiting to receive. B0100000023be50
```

And I can’t do anything at all unless I exit `tmux`. The situation about `sz` is similar with `rz`,the info is:

```
B00000000000000*
```

And I can’t do anything unless I exit `tmux`, too.

Software versions are:

- **tmux:** 1.8 (default config)
- **szsz (lrzsz):** 0.12.20
- **rzrz (lrzsz):** 0.12.20

Answer (score 1):

A new rz/sz tools [trzsz](https://github.com/trzsz/trzsz) which works with iTerm2 and tmux.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that Tmux does not support rz and sz. This is stated clearly in the [Tmux wiki page](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#why-dont-xmodem-ymodem-and-zmodem-work-inside-tmux).

Answer (score -2):

> In GNU Screen, you can enable zmodem transfers, so that even if all you have is a serial terminal connection, you can still transfer files (Ctrl+a :zmodem catch followed by typing sz  on the remote end.) Tmux does not support zmodem transfer.

Reference: https://www.wikivs.com/wiki/screen_vs_tmux

Try samba.

Comment: Can you include some detail from the link? This is in case the link is removed in the future. Please see [answer].

Comment: The essential part of the reference article is added to the quoted block.

Comment: Like Burgi said, the answer is garbage and like he guessed the link is dead.
The correct answer for "screen" would have been:
Press: 'CTRL+A' 
Enter: ':'
Write: 'zmodem pass'